# Automatically notify a user when event date approach

Tags: php, laravel, events, notifications

I have a table called `events` where all the user created events are registered. Its structure is like this:  `id`, `user_id`, `event_at` and `event`

So what I want is to create a new notification when the `event_at` time approach in the backend. It will be like even if no users are in any route this should be run and a new notification should be created in the database. I have setup the notification table and class. So all I want to know is how to run this command on the time approch.

```
$event->user->notify(new NotifyAtEvent($event));
```

where the `$event` is the particular event.

Comment: You should use scheduling in laravel. https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/artisan#scheduling-artisan-commands

Comment: @Rajeevbbqq Is there any blog post or any videos which I can refer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel's command scheduler allows you to fluently and expressively define your command schedule within Laravel itself. When using the scheduler, only a single Cron entry is needed on your server. Your task schedule is defined in the `app/Console/Kernel.php` file's schedule method.

You can read docs regarding about by [clicking here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling)

or [Watch](https://laracasts.com/series/intermediate-laravel/episodes/1) series of Jeffrey Way.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use Laravel Task Scheduling and cronjobs. For example , you have a cronjob that runs the script daily and on that function in laravel you check if you have any event that you have to send emails.

Here is the documentation reference, it is straightforward.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scheduling

Comment: Can I use campaign monitor?

Comment: Is there any blog post or any videos which I can refer?